# Problem Onclick + "v" does not recognize the methods in android studio code

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener

I am fairly new to programming, I was writing an application code in Android Studio but had a problem
It turns out that when I put this line in my code (In image)
it does not detect it and an error occurs both with "onClick" and with "(v)" I reached this point and I don't know how to solve it
Attached images:

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/huZLu.png Error Code
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJYJ.png All Code
I would really appreciate the answer
This problem is eating my head!
Thank you

Comment: remove onClick, only keep v in brackets

Comment: Assuming you are targeting Java settings at 1.8, mOpcion2.setOnClickListener { view -> finish(); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not a big problem, you can write like this, it will solve your issue

```
 mOpicon2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you!
Yes, it really was simple, but as a newbie I couldn't find that logic!

Comment: Its common to get this error. good luck

Comment: I was about to give you a vote but got another error from this solution
It turns out that now the app starts in this secondary activity and not in the first activity, nor does it allow leaving the app or activating it (I don't know if it's due to the override)
¿Do you know how I can solve it D:?

Comment: can you elaborate the problem with some code of yours?

Comment: add also explain the working of your app?